Why archive disc images of optical discs instead of just their files?
When archiving data (not music) on optical data discs like CDs/DVDs/BluRay discs (to another storage medium such as a HDD), what are the benefits/use cases of archiving the entire disc content as an optical disc image file instead of just the files, which use less storage space than disk image and, in my experience, are also more compressible than disk images ?

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_disc_image:
An optical disc image (or ISO image, from the ISO 9660 file system used with CD-ROM media) is a disk image that contains everything that would be written to an optical disc, disk sector by disc sector, including the optical disc file system.

The only use case that comes to (my) mind is backup of software, whose copy protection does not only rely on the files but also on information that would be stored in the disc image.
What other benefits and/or use cases are there? Can you name/explain some?
What could I be missing if I only backup the data files on optical discs instead of the whole image?

I expect this is a non-exclusive list but -

By doing a bitcopy of the image you can checksum it and ensure nothing is corrupt a lot more easily.
The image becomes OS/filesystem agnostic.  This is more important than you think as there are lots of variants of filesystems.
You can preserve the boot mechanisms used by the image.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660 makes interesting reading and goes through many nuances of the format which could/would be lost if you just back up the files. (eg El Torito for booting, Joliet/Romeo for filenames, file sizes, hybrid filesystems - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_disc has more details)
Indeed I imagine that copy protection would be very low down the list of things, as often the copy protection relies on a read FAILING from a disc image - which won't happen on a bit copy of the drive.
Also, an ISO is easy to present as standardised read-only disk - even a boot disk, which is useful for VM images and copying to usb pen drives.
I am not sure your contention that files or more compressible then disk images is valid.  The disk image will only be the size of the contents of what is written (ie the image won't be the full 800megs of the CDRom if the actual data on the disk is less).  There would likely be padding of blocks, but these would be very compressible, comprising of just zero's.
Addendum
Re Checksums of an ISO - Very often when a file is distributed, the checksums are also advised.  Once the file has been acquired, running the downloaded version of the file through the same checksumming program will allow you to confirm that the file you have is the same as the file on the distributors website (and not corrupted or modified by a third party).
The examples of checksumming are all over the place, but look at https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview for an overview of Ubuntu's explanation and tutorial - and similarly https://ostechnix.com/verify-linux-iso-image-integrity-and-authenticity/

Great answer, thank you. About compressibility: This is my personal observations from using advanced archivers such as 7-zip, which have file-type specific compression algorithms (for example for .wav files or .bmp files). These algorithms don't work (as good) on raw image files. I tested that. You may be right that, in theory, compressibility would not suffer, but in practice it can matter due to file formats not being detected inside an image and thus not being optimally compressed.

First I've heard of z-zip having file specific compression algorythms.  Do you have an example of that?  (Everything I've seen shows it setting the compression type per archive, not per file.  I wonder if its a dictionary size thing rather then a file thing.

@ "First I've heard of z-zip having file specific compression algorythms. Do you have an example of that?" yes: https://archive.is/Bf000#selection-2417.8-2417.116 You could test that by compressing a data CD full of .wav or .bmp files versus compressing the ISO image. It's a long time ago that I tried, but from my memory the compressed ISO image always had considerably bigger file size. What else could explain this other than file-type specific compression not kicking in?

@ davidgo: "By doing a bitcopy of the image you can checksum it and ensure nothing is corrupt a lot more easily." --> Could you please elaborate, I don't quite understand. What is the workflow and why is it easier (than what exactly) ?

I just ran a test using 7z for Linux using 97 megs of BMP's + 306 megs of regular files - ie the contents of my linux /boot folder (no special arguments), and my results were suprisingly the opposite to your anecdote.  The iso was made using mkisofs - and the result was - test.iso was 398M, test.z7 (the compressed file version) was 309M, and surprisingly the z7 of the iso was only 307M.    (The tar.gz was 332M and taring and using bz2 was 322M)

For a meaningful comparison, the CD must only contain files of 1 specific file type (i.e. only .wav files or only .bmp files) to test file-type specific compression. If you throw in other files into the mix, you don't know how these impact the outcome.

Re your link - that only seems to refer to RAR compression.  Why would you use RAR if you want the most compression?  I'll rerun my test with only bmp files shortly.    I'll update my answer shortly to answer your question about checksums - its to long for a comment.

You said you never heard of file-type specific compression and requested an example. I provided one. A web search may find more.

Just did a second 7z test with only bmp files and the iso and raw files were, as expected, virtually identical (with the compressed iso again being very, very marginally smaller - 42104458 bytes vs 42105143 bytes (so a saving of 685 bytes).  It is disappointing to me that you seem to be looking to corner cases to evidence a evidence a general assertion - ie rar.     The same "file specifc" compression would hold true in in a 7zip of the iso and the 7zip of the raw files - but the usage case for creating iso is not backing up bmp's or wavs.

@ davidgo: Again, I only provided a link to an example because you asked for one. It was not intended at all to evidence a general assertion, but to evidence that file-type specific compression exists, since you stated you never heard of it. I thank you very much for your tests, which are surprising to me (how can files+ISO overhead compress more than the files themselves??) and don't match my longstanding albeit not very recent experience. I will certainly make new tests. Thank you very much for sharing your test results, very interesting!

There no advantage in saving "just the files" because the overhead for a complete and usable ISO image file is negligible.
There are obvious advantages in saving re-encoded files from optical media (e.g. X264 or X265 (HEVC) MKV containers or others for video; MP3, OGG and in a lesser extend FLAC - better quality (lossless) but much bigger files) for audio).
The use case for ISO backups is NOT only software backup and even in that case many copy protection methods don't allow for an usable copy of the installation media.
The use case for ISO backups is mostly for media disks (without copy protection) that can be "burn" into blank media and work indistinguishably from the original disks.
If you're considering simple DATA disks (i.e. media usually suffixed by "-ROM") then there's almost never any advantage of backing up them as ISO image files, other than an organization preference.

I've mentioned all the scenarios. In a nutshell, no advantage whatsoever in saving just the data files.

@summerrain - This answer still stands.
